# How do I grab figures from a url and place them in my page?

Tags: html, pull

http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/ has several figures that I would like to display on my html page.

If I just have a div and say I want it to display how much percent some financial market has changed, how to I get the div to display whatever figure is published to Bloomberg? So that whenever I reload my website the most up to date figure from Bloomberg is displayed in plain text in my div?

So instead of

```
<div>0.05%</div>
```

I have

```
<div>(some code here to pull the correct figure from bloomberg)</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bloomberg has an API that you can use to get their market data for free:

http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/

> Now, you can adopt Bloomberg’s market data interfaces without cost or restriction.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is called data parsing and it is pretty common request. If you want to do it using PHP, [PHP Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) provide plenty of examples.